# <body <?php body_class(); ?>> as a Function?

Tags: css, wordpress, function

I want to run the below CSS only for users that are **not** logged in.

```
um-faicon-link {
display:none;
}
```

I know you can add the body_class template tag in the theme to do ([reference here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/)) this but is it possible to do it via a function instead?

Comment: if you have `function body_class(){ echo 'class="um-faicon-link"';}` then yes?

Comment: `class="..."` * @castis

Comment: whoops! fantastic catch @MattiaNocerino

Comment: Thanks guys but can you please celebrate on Mattia correction?
I'm guessing `function body_class(){ echo class="um-faicon-link";}` is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As WordPress should add the `logged-in` class to the body of the document for a user who's logged in anyway, could you simply arrange your CSS like this? (Assuming your `um-faicon-link` is a classname...)

```
.um-faicon-link {
  display: none;
}

.logged-in .um-faicon-link {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

Add body tag like below in your header.php file

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

In your theme functions.php file add below code-

```
function my_body_classes( $classes ) 
{
  // Add a class to body tag
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
$classes[] = 'user-loggedin'; //if user is logged in then this class will apply to body tag
}
else
{
  $classes[] = 'um-faicon-link'; //if user is not logged in then this class will apply to body tag
}
  return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_classes');
```